# Enviar imagem via post

Tags: http, http-post

No facebook, eu perecebi que, ao selecionar uma imagem para colocar na postagem, eles enviavam uma requisição pelo método POST para uma URL lá(que deveria tratar de fazer o upload..)

Mas, o que estranhei, é que o conteúdo do post parecia com isso:

```
-----------------------------24055831728377 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fb_dtsg" AQF_UrnMtkOL 
-----------------------------24055831728377 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source" 8 
-----------------------------24055831728377 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_id"..............
```

...

```
ÿØÿà�JFIF��`�`��ÿî�Adobe�d����ÿá]Exif��MM�*����2�������b;�������vGF�������GI�����?����������ê�������i�������}���ç2009:03:12 13:46:42�Corbis���������¿�������Ó����54������54��ê���´��������2008:03:14 13:59:26�2008:03:14 13:59:26���������������)������1������9�������������H������H���ÿØÿà�JFIF������ÿÛ�C� ...
```

..

e terminava com:

```
-----------------------------24055831728377 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_id" 1024 
-----------------------------24055831728377--
```

Os caracteres estranhos ali seriam o que, o código da imagem? Nunca vi essa de enviar por POST uma imagem, como funciona isso?

Comment: Poderia colocar a linha completa onde aparecem os caracteres estranhos?

Comment: @Qmechanic73, Bah, é muito grande mesmo.. vou colocar um pouco mais, acredito que os caracteres em si não importam pra nós, acho que é código da imagem, que no final resulta nela ele por inteiro, mas não sei confirmar nada disso..

Comment: Isso é o base64 da imagem, provavelmente.

Comment: Acredito que não @FelipeAvelar, veja: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64, segundo essa definição que vi é claro..

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus, é muito comum em tecnologias web transmitir arquivos e dados segundo essa codificação, não estou dizendo que é esse o caso, mas parece muito ser... Um exemplo de [como converter uma imagem para base64](https://exagon.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/convertendo-imagens-em-base64-em-5-linguagens-diferentes-php-c-java-pythonjavascript/)

Comment: Acho que descobri, eu usei o `file_get_contents()` que eu observei no link que me enviou, e o código que gera é igual ao do POST no facebook(a parte estranha), ou seja, a imagem não foi codificada, aquele código todo ali é o conteúdo da imagem, agora resta a dúvida é, como eu recebo todo esse código na outra página e interpreto para ele virar uma imagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se vai enviar um arquivo para o servidor é necessário usar uma codificação que permita enviar dados binários juntamente com dados de formulário.

Normalmente um POST sem arquivos no formulário possui um corpo com o seguinte formato:

```
campo1=1234&campo2=Miguel&campo3=30
```

Esse formato é idêntico ao formato da query-string na URI.

Note que não seria possível enviar um arquivo binário com esse formato, a não ser que fosse transformado em algum formato de texto, tal como base-64. Mas esse não é o caso, pois base-64 ou qualquer outra codificação de texto iria sem dúvida aumentar o tamanho do request.

Para isso existe um formato de codificação que permite o envio de dados binários: `multipart/form-data`.

## Codificação `multipart/form-data`

Essa codificação é que permite transmitir para o servidor os arquivos em formato binário mesmo. Está definida no protocolo [HTTP 1.1 seção 3.7.2 Multipart Types](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html) ([rfc1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt)).

O formato de codificação consta em gerar separadores aleatórios, e separar cada campo do formulário com esse separador.

Veja um exemplo de POST usando esta codificação: ([exemplo deste site](http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html))

```
POST /diretorio/arquivo HTTP/1.0
Host: www.dominio.com.br
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
Content-Length: 381

--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="campo1"

1234
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="campo2"

Miguel
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="arquivo1"; filename="minha-foto.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

ÿØÿà�JFIF��`�`��ÿî�Adobe�d����ÿá]Exif��MM�*����2�������b;�������vGF�������GI�����?������
--AaB03x--
```

Algumas regras de formação do conteúdo:

1. Cabeçalho `Content-type`: deve ser `multipart/form-data; boundary=$divisor-aleatorio` substituindo o divisor aleatório por algo realmente aleatório e com chance quase 0 de se repetir no conteúdo do arquivo binário ou em qualquer campo enviado.
2. Cabeçalho `Content-Length`: deve possuir o tamanho do request, contando desde o primeiro divisor (no exemplo anterior é`--AaB03x`), até o último caractere do terminador (``--AaB03x--)
3. Para cada campo ou arquivo:

   1. adicionar o divisor
   2. adicionar cabeçalhos da divisão:

      - `content-disposition: form-data`
      - `name="nome-do-campo-no-html"`
      - se for arquivo:

        - `filename="nome-do-arquivo-sendo-enviado"`: somente se for arquivo
        - `Content-Type: image/jpeg`: tipo mime do arquivo
        - `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`
      - pula uma linha, e então envia os dados
      - logo que terminar já vem outro divisor do próximo campo ou o terminador
   3. adicionar terminador

### Submetendo `form` com `multipart/form-data`

No HTML, para indicar que deseja usar a codificação `multipart/form-data`, basta incluir na tag `form` o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

[Documentação da tag `form` na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Segundo a documentação da MDN, isso é necessário quando se usa um `input` com `type="file"`.